# Stochastic Systems French translation

Tags: translation-request, mathematical-french

What is the english translation for this sentence

**Principe du Maximum Stochastique en contrôle optimal pour des systèmes avec Changement de Régime**

I'm stuck in the ''**Changement de Régime**'' part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means literally "regime change". A "regime" in this context is normally an external input in a model, for example high and low volatility in a financial context can represent 2 regimes. The model might have different parameters for both regimes.